# Testing Reactive Spring webflux using WebTestClient application context

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux, junit5, webtestclient

I am trying to test the following spring webflux Kotlin application with the WebTestClient and Junit 5:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class ReactiveKataApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplicationBuilder(ReactiveKataApplication::class.java)
            .initializers(
                beans {
                    bean {
                        router {
                            GET("/frp/hello") {
                                ServerResponse.ok().body(Mono.just("Hello"), String::class.java)
                            }
                        }
                    }
            })
            .build()
            .run(*args)
}
```

I have the following test which is failing with a 404, can anyone help me identify the issue?

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@SpringBootTest
class ReactiveKataApplicationContextTest {

    private lateinit var webTestClient : WebTestClient

    @Autowired
    lateinit var context: ApplicationContext

    @BeforeAll
    fun initClient() {
        webTestClient = WebTestClient
                .bindToApplicationContext(context)
                .configureClient()
                .build()
    }

    @Test
    fun `calling hello world endpoint returns 200`() {
        webTestClient.get().uri("/frp/hello")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk
    }

}
```

In the test log I see that the context is the ReactiveKataApplicationContext*Test* rather than the actual application, can anyone assist in resolving this using the WebTestClient binding to the Application Context?

```
2020-01-29 12:01:27.538  INFO 16269 --- [           main] c.o.r.ReactiveKataApplicationContextTest : Started ReactiveKataApplicationContextTest in 1.666 seconds (JVM running for 3.157)
```

I have tried `@SpringBootTest(classes = [ ReactiveKataApplication::class ])` to no avail.

Git repo here: https://github.com/stefan-cross/reactive-spring-kata

Comment: if you run it with out tests can you confirm that the endpoint is served if you go to it manually

Comment: well i have no idea what you are doing. I suggest you do it like they do it in the documentation, instead of autowiring in your own context, and trying to attach it etc. etc. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-with-mock-environment you probably need to add the `@AutoConfigureWebTestClient` annotation and remove all the context autowiring.